# Cotangent Fields: Exactness vs. Conservation

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Given a smooth manifold.

Then a cotangent field is exact iff conservative:
$$\alpha\in\mathcal{X}^*(M):\quad\alpha=\mathrm{d}h\iff\oint\alpha=0$$
How to prove this properly?

Comment: You compute the derivative locally, so you do that computation in a coordinate chart. (Integrate from a base point $p_0\in M$ to $p\in M$, choose a coordinate chart centered at $p$, and for $q$ near $p$ write $\int_{p_0}^q \alpha = \int_{p_0}^p\alpha + \int_p^q\alpha$, and work only with the latter. Also, the fact that $\oint \alpha = 0$ tells you the integral is path-independent, hence $h$ is well-defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This proof is taken from Lee's Smooth Manifolds.*

Consider up to a constant:
$$h(x)=\int_z^x\alpha$$

Regard a smooth coordinate path:
$$\gamma:[0,\varepsilon)\to M:\quad\hat{\gamma}(t):=(0,\ldots,0,t,0,\ldots,0)\quad(\gamma(0)=z)$$
So one obtains as partial derivatives:
$$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x^i}(z)=\gamma'(0)h=\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}(h\circ\gamma)=\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}\int_z^{\gamma(t)}\alpha\\=\left.\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\right|_{t=0}\int_0^t\alpha(\gamma'(s))\mathrm{d}s=\alpha(\gamma'(0))=\alpha^i(z)$$
*(This especially shows smoothness.)*